# html input type button within a hidden div shrink on hide() show() toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form which has a hidden `<div>` that shows up when a button is clicked. There are input fields in that hidden `<div>` that includes buttons

When I first click 'Add' the div shows up as it should. I close the div by pressing Cancel and then I reclick 'Add' the div shows buttons that have shrunk in size.

check the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uc3Ef/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are setting the `value` attribute of all `input` elements to nothing and the `value` attribute is used as the label text for the buttons.

Change this:

```
$('.hiddenDiv').find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val("");
});
```

To:

```
$('.hiddenDiv').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
     $(this).val("");
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uc3Ef/1/

Also, you do not need to use `.each()` here, you can just do this:

```
$('.hiddenDiv').find('input[type="text"]').val("");
```

This works because `.val(STRING)` will set the value of all selected elements. Here is the documentation for `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uc3Ef/3/

Answer (score 2):

You're clearing the value when you click on `cancel`

```
$(this).val("");
```

Answer (score 2):

they are "shrinking" because you are wiping out the value (which is the text the button displays).

Remove this line from the Cancel button click event and try again :)

```
$(this).val("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the value of inputs to `""` and your input selector selects the buttons, you can use `input[type="text"]` instead, also there is no need to use `each` method, you can use:

```
 $('.hiddenDiv').find('input[type="text"]').val("");
```

jQuery `show()` method is equal to `css('display', 'block')`, using `show()` for revealing the element is sufficient:

```
 $('.hiddenDiv').show();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uc3Ef/5/)